# Live Heroku App has all broken images except background image (React/Node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

When the site is live every image except the background images hard coded in CSS come up as broken.

I build the app from the master branch on Github. On the repository all images load fine and extensions are not broken/different to the background image. The background image is in the same directory as the others and worked when I hosted on Netlify absolutely fine.

On console the images come up with a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Live site: https://deathless-studio.herokuapp.com/#/

Repository that images are in: https://github.com/matthew-devonport/DEATHLESS-Portfolio/tree/master/server/public/Images

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web client is calling the images via

```
https://deathless-studio.herokuapp.com/IMAGES/Shop-Pics-Logo.jpg
```

instead of

```
https://deathless-studio.herokuapp.com/Images/Shop-Pics-Logo.jpg
```

(Try out the links. As you can see the images are there. Just the specified path was incorrect.)

If you do `F12` or ctrl+shift+i and open the network tab you see the failing API calls:

[image]

And this is your git repository:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with only Heroku. Because The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral 
https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

You can use

1. S3 File Upload 
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node
2. Clodinary add-ons 
    https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary

Good Luck :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the filesystem being ephemeral. He committed/versioned the files. Ephemeral refers to the temporary files created during runtime. They are not saved on restart.

Comment: wait, I'm not uploading images from a site, these images are all static like the background. Maybe on the components are uploading the image path incorrectly?

Comment: @Matthew-Devonport You`re welcome I would want more benefit this problem

Comment: @TinNguyen Yeah I saw you solved right way.thanks feedback and solution

Comment: @Matthew-Devonport Yes as you think :) .problem is a path. I appreciate to Tin